# Maths formula of cleaner way for bounding box logic?

Tags: ios, swift

Below I have written some bounding box logic which is a bit verbose. Is there a way to make it more readable, so the check looks cleaner and more concise?

```
func validatePosition(position:SCNVector3, forNode node:SCNNode) -> SCNVector3 {
    var newPosition = position
    var maxVector = SCNVector3Zero
    var minVector = SCNVector3Zero

    let success = self.actionDelegate?.getBoundingBox(&minVector, max: &maxVector)
    guard success == true else {
        return newPosition
    }

    if newPosition.x < minVector.x && newPosition.x < 0 {
        newPosition.x = minVector.x
    }

    if newPosition.y < minVector.y && newPosition.y < 0 {
        newPosition.y = minVector.y
    }

    if newPosition.z < minVector.z && newPosition.z < 0 {
        newPosition.z = minVector.z
    }

    if newPosition.x > maxVector.x && newPosition.x > 0 {
        newPosition.x = maxVector.x
    }

    if newPosition.y > maxVector.y && newPosition.y > 0 {
        newPosition.y = maxVector.y
    }

    if newPosition.z > maxVector.z && newPosition.z > 0 {
        newPosition.z = maxVector.z
    }

    return newPosition
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension ClosedInterval {
    func clamp(value : Bound) -> Bound {
        return self.start > value ? self.start
            : self.end < value ? self.end
            : value
    }
}

extension SCNVector3 {
    func clamp(min min:SCNVector3, max: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        let x = (min.x...max.x).clamp(self.x)
        let y = (min.y...max.y).clamp(self.y)
        let z = (min.z...max.z).clamp(self.z)
        return SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    }
}

func validatePosition(position:SCNVector3, forNode node:SCNNode) -> SCNVector3 {
    var newPosition = position
    var maxVector = SCNVector3Zero
    var minVector = SCNVector3Zero

    let success = self.actionDelegate?.getBoundingBox(&minVector, max: &maxVector)
    guard success == true else {
        return newPosition
    }

    newPosition = position.clamp(min: minVector, max: maxVector)
    return newPosition
}
```